# Add button click handler in Qt project, Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have Qt SDK and Visual Studio Qt Add-In working in VS2008. I created Qt UI project with main window class MainWindow. Double-click on mainwindow.ui opens Qt Designer. Then I added push button to the window, and called it pushButton. In Signals-Slots mode I managed to connect button's clicked signal with MainWindow ButtonClicked slot. Signal/Slot editor looks like this:

```
Sender   pushButton
Signal   clicked()
Receiver MainWindowClass
Slot     ButtonClicked()
```

mainwindow.ui file was changed, reflecting this new information. However, mainwindow.cpp and mainwindow.h remain unchanged. I expect to see the place where I can add my own code. So, I added this code manually:

```
// mainwindow.h
...
protected slots:
    void ButtonClicked();

// mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::ButtonClicked()
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Clicked");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

It works, but I wonder whether this is correct way to do this. Is slot declaration and implementation supposed to be added manually, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use signal/slot editor, you have to add these codes manually. Old Qt Add-In was automatically add these if you double click on a button from designer. Now Qt Designer is a seperate application. Double clicking is not possible.

Also you can use [automatic connections](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#automatic-connections). With automatic connections you dont need to connect signals with slots. Functions which has special naming convention, automatically called. Like `on_okButton_clicked`.